# Trouble Putting Figure in \resizebox

Tags: floats, scaling

I would like to create an array of `tikzpictures` on a beamer slide by beginning a `figure` environment and creating four `subfloats` inside it (using the `subfigure` package). Strangely, this exact process worked twice on two slides before the one I am currently working on, but failed when I did it the third time. I have been breaking my head over it, but cannot seem to find what the problem is.

Here is a minimum working example that still manages to produce the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{\begin{figure}\end{figure}}
\end{document}
```

And here is the error itself:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 ...zebox{10cm}{!}{\begin{figure}\end{figure}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `figure` environment is a floating environment.  You should be resizing the actual content (graphic) of the figure, not the floating environment.

```
\begin{figure}
    \resizebox{10cm}{!}{\includegraphics{foo.png}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: In beamer `figure` is not a float but a simple `center` environment (which you can't put in a horizontal box like `\resizebox` either as it build as list).