# how to make a graphic bigger

Tags: graphics, sweave, size

I've made the following syntax:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{xxx }
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE >>=
load("//d049nt01/estudios$/Indicadores de Liquidacion/Tablas de prueba/pago_agg.rda")
jub <- pago_agg[c(1:10),]
jub$RACSCODIGO <- as.numeric(jub$RACSCODIGO)
jub <- jub[with(jub, order(RACSCODIGO)),]

par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3) 
barplot(jub$HAB_MED)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(jub$RACSCODIGO, jub$CANT, type = "l", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "Monto de Jubilación en pesos")
points(jub$CANT)
text( jub$RACSCODIGO, jub$CANT, jub$CANT, pos = 3)
axis(side=4, at = pretty(range(jub$CANT)))
mtext("Cantidad de Solicitudes con Jubilación", side=4, line=3)
@

\end{figure}
```

I want to make the graphic bigger proportionally in the PDF, but without considering it an image, for example .jpg, .png, etc.

EDIT - reproducible example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Test}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE >>=
barplot(rnorm(10,0,1),rnorm(10,0,1))
@
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could give `\resizebox` a try, as described in the answer of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61634/trouble-putting-figure-in-resizebox

Comment: @StefanBraun, thanks I edited the question. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem when making my figures have the same width as my text as the default size of a figure in Sweave is 0.8 of the linewidth. To overcome this I had to manually set the value after \begin{document} but before making the graphics call.

`\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth}`

Let me know if this is what were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a file from the R project. You can compile it to pdf with `Sweave("path/to/your/file.Rnw")`. This will result in a new .df file that contains your graphic. Now you can include this pdf in your document with the `\includegraphics` command.

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{path/to/the/generated/file.pdf}
```

`\includegraphics` has options like scale, width or height. You can adjust the image size with these.